# How to draw a line connecting a label to its position on OpenLayers3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I need to draw a line connecting a point to its label. Like this:

[image]

The 'Y' has coordinates, the label is in a different position on the screen by using offSet. I also can drag the label around by changing its offset, and I need the line to adapt when I do that so they remain connected.

Is there any way to draw a line on the map without providing coordinates to it? Because I only have one set of coordinates and an offset.

This is how I created the point:

```
    configLabel(offsetx,offsety,label){
    labelStyle = new ol.style.Style({
        text: new ol.style.Text({
            font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: color }),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#fff', width: 2
            }),
            text: label,
            offsetY: offsety,
            offsetX: offsetx
        })
    });
}

pointStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
        anchor: [0.5, 25],
        anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
        anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
        src: 'img/point.ico'
    })
});

var point = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(coord));
point.setStyle(pointStyle);
layerSource.addFeature(point);

var label1 = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(coord));
var style = configLabel(0,15, 'line1');
label1.setStyle(style);
layerSource.addFeature(label1);

var label2 = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(coord));
var style = configLabel(0,30, 'line2');
label2.setStyle(style);
layerSource.addFeature(label2);

var label3 = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(coord));
var style = configLabel(0,45, 'line3');
label3.setStyle(style);
layerSource.addFeature(label3);

var label4 = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(coord));
var style = configLabel(0,60, 'line4');
label4.setStyle(style);
layerSource.addFeature(label4);
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You received just a great answer, a feedback is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any way to draw lines in by pixel values rather than coordinate values in OpenLayers 3 styles. You could however use a [style function](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/apidoc/ol.style.html#.StyleFunction), which takes the resolution as an argument and use the resolution to create a geometry from the desired pixel offsets.

Since the resolution is provided as the number of map units per pixel, finding a position from a given pixel is trivial: You multiply the pixel offset with the resolution.

A runnable example can be found in the snippet below.

```js
var feature = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point([0, 0]));

var source = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: [feature]
});


var fill = new ol.style.Fill({
  color: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)'
});
var stroke = new ol.style.Stroke({
  color: '#3399CC',
  width: 1.25
});
var pointStyle = new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Circle({
    fill: fill,
    stroke: stroke,
    radius: 5,
  })
})
var lineLabelStyle = function(pointCoord, offsetX, offsetY, resolution, text) {
  var labelCoord = [
    pointCoord[0] + offsetX * resolution,
    pointCoord[1] - offsetY * resolution,
  ];
  return [
    new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: stroke,
      geometry: new ol.geom.LineString([pointCoord, labelCoord])
    }),
    new ol.style.Style({
      text: new ol.style.Text({
        text: text,
        textAlign: "left",
        offsetY: offsetY,
        offsetX: offsetX,
      })
    })
  ];
};
var styleFunction = function(feature, resolution) {
  var pointCoord = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()
  return [pointStyle].concat(
    lineLabelStyle(pointCoord, 50, -10, resolution, "Label 1"),
    lineLabelStyle(pointCoord, 50, 5, resolution, "Label 2"),
    lineLabelStyle(pointCoord, 50, 20, resolution, "Label 3")
  )
}
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: source,
      style: styleFunction
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/build/ol.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

Comment: In case someone else wants this example in a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/hmug4cbz/.